# erlang: scheduler overhead running processes

Tags: erlang

It's a simple program, and my machine has two CPU cores.
I expect that when I spawn two processes, the consuming time is the same as when I spawn only one process.

```
-module(test).
-export([main/1]).
forRange(Begin,End,Total) when Begin < End ->
  forRange(Begin+1,End,Total+Begin);
forRange(_,_,Total)->
  io:format("~p ~n", [Total]),
  ok.
main([A, B])->
  process_flag(trap_exit, true),
  Pids = [spawn_link(fun() -> forRange(1,list_to_integer(A),0) end) || _ <- lists:seq(1, list_to_integer(B))],
  [ receive
    {'EXIT', Pid, normal} ->
      ok
  end || Pid <- Pids ].
```

The test result is:

```
$ time escript test.beam 1000000000 1
499999999500000000 

real    0m3.895s
user    0m3.820s
sys 0m0.068s
$ time escript test.beam 1000000000 2
499999999500000000 
499999999500000000 

real    0m4.582s
user    0m8.788s
sys 0m0.168s
```

However, the result shows that when I spawn two processes, the real time is bigger than the case of one process, which means there is some overhead at the Erlang scheduler? But for this simple example, the processes should run in exact parallel.

Comment: Have you considered that for any process count greater than 1, `main` has to spawn multiple processes and then receive multiple messages from those multiple processes, which automatically means more processing that can't occur in parallel? Have you also considered that you're creating a new anonymous fun to be spawned and calling `list_to_integer/1` once for each process to be spawned, and these operations won't occur in parallel either?

Comment: Those things you said cost so much time? I don't think so.

Comment: Sorry, already commented on your other question, but once more, to make test more precise please exclude from it VM startup time. You can do it from erlang console, bofore your first test make sure module is loaded (just call test:module_info()) and then you may use timer:tc/3 to measure execution time.

Comment: Also remember from your question on escript's run-time that you should be compiling the code first. Unless you plan to run all your code in escript uncompiled, you're measuring something totally different than your planned use-case.

Comment: @danechkin, both tests should have the same time consuming at the vm startup. so what's your point exactly?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot, you could see that my example already use compiled version (*.beam)

Comment: Nowhere did I say "those things...cost so much time." But they do have a definite cost. Did you try reducing or eliminating those costs? I did, and it makes a noticeable difference. The point is that you're posting a question about performance and jumping to a conclusion about schedulers, but you haven't eliminated obvious sources of serialization in your own code.

Comment: @SteveVinoski, could you share your enhancement codes? I'm Erlang newbie, and in fact, I am not sure whether it's scheduler related problem, so no conclusion yet to me.

Comment: I suppose that @SteveVinoski means that you can put `list_to_integer/1` calls outside of the list comprehension. You are trying to convert a string -> integer multiple times for no reason, neither `A` nor `B` changes.

Answer (score 3):

I have modified your code little bit for compiled module.

```
-module(test).
-export([test/2]).

forRange(Begin,End,Total) when Begin < End ->
    forRange(Begin+1,End,Total+Begin);
forRange(_,_,Total)->
    io:format("~p ~n", [Total]),
    ok.

test(A, B)->
    Flag = process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    Pids = [spawn_link(fun() -> forRange(1,A,0) end) || _ <- lists:seq(1, B)],
    [ receive
          {'EXIT', Pid, normal} ->
              ok
      end || Pid <- Pids ],
    process_flag(trap_exit, Flag).
```

Then I compile and run.

```
$ erlc test.erl
$ erl -tbt
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.0  (abort with ^G)
1> timer:tc(fun() -> test:test(500000000,1) end).
124999999750000000 
{8218153,true}
2> timer:tc(fun() -> test:test(500000000,1) end).
124999999750000000 
{8292624,true}
3> timer:tc(fun() -> test:test(500000000,2) end).
124999999750000000 
124999999750000000 
{9119394,true}
4> timer:tc(fun() -> test:test(500000000,2) end).
124999999750000000 
124999999750000000 
{9116651,true}
5> (9116651+9119394)/(8218153+8292624).
1.10449344691652
```

As you can see I did two things on purpose. First I locked schedulers to the CPU cores and second I choose number of repetition to run it longer, it is almost 10s. The purpose is to make it more predictable, give more time to schedulers to arrange work and also to make measurement more stable. As you can see diference is now only 10%. I have modern CPU (model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU M 520 @ 2.40GHz) which allows automatic overclocking if only one CPU core is used which I tend to blame this difference to.

If you would like to see the scheduler overhead you should try more processes:

```
1> timer:tc(fun() -> test:test(100000000,16) end).
4999999950000000 
...
4999999950000000 
{13466677,true}
2> timer:tc(fun() -> test:test(100000000,16) end).
...
{13625811,true}
3> timer:tc(fun() -> test:test(100000000,32) end).
...
{27325526,true}
4> timer:tc(fun() -> test:test(100000000,32) end).
...
{27461209,true}
5> (27325526+27461209)/(13466677+13625811)/2.
1.0111056430107122
```

And now this 1.1% you can probably blame to the schdeulers overhead.

Answer (score 0):

In the '2' case, you're creating twice as many processes.
Since the process that's doing the spawning is single threaded, it's going to take longer to spawn twice as many.
A better way to demonstrate what I think you're looking to show would be to spawn B processes, each of which spawns A processes.   That way, the actual spawning is also done in parallel.

Comment: In case '2' there is one more process to spawn and I can assure you it doesn't take 600ms. It is more like 600ns or less.